# Having trouble indexing into recipe with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a program to iterate through a recipe website, the Woks of Life, and extract each recipe and store it in a CSV file. I have managed to extract the links for storage purpose, but I am having trouble extracting the elements on the page. The website link is https://thewoksoflife.com/baked-white-pepper-chicken-wings/. The elements that I am trying to reach are the name, cook time, ingredients, calories, instructions, etc.

```
def parse_recipe(link):
    #hardcoded link for now until i get it working
    page = requests.get("https://thewoksoflife.com/baked-white-pepper-chicken-wings/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    for i in soup.findAll("script", {"class": "yoast-schema-graph yoast-schema-graph--main"}):
        print(i.get("name")) #should print "Baked White Pepper Chicken Wings" but prints "None"
```

For reference, when I print(i), I get:

```
<script class="yoast-schema-graph yoast-schema-graph--main" type="application/ld+json"> 
   {"@context":"https://schema.org","@graph": 
   [{"@type":"Organization","@id":"https://thewoksoflife.com/#organization","name":"The Woks of 
    Life","url":"https://thewoksoflife.com/","sameAs": 
   ["https://www.facebook.com/thewoksoflife","https://twitter.com/thewoksoflife"],"logo": 
{"@type":"ImageObject","@id":"https://thewoksoflife.com/#logo","url":"https://thewoksoflife.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2019/05/Temporary-Logo-e1556728319201.png","width":365,"height":364,"caption":"The 
Woks of Life"},"image":{"@id":"https://thewoksoflife.com/#logo"}}{"@type":"WebSite","@id":"https://thewoksoflife.com/#website","url":"https://thewoksoflife.com/","name": 
   "The Woks of Life","description":"a culinary genealogy","publisher": 
   {"@id":"https://thewoksoflife.com/#organization"},"potentialAction": 
   {"@type":"SearchAction","target":"https://thewoksoflife.com/?s={search_term_string}","query- 
   input":"required name=search_term_string"}}, 
   {"@type":"ImageObject","@id":"https://thewoksoflife.com/baked-white-pepper-chicken- 
   wings/#primaryimage","url":"https://thewoksoflife.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/white-pepper- 
   chicken-wings-9.jpg","width":600,"height":836,"caption":"Crispy Baked White Pepper Chicken Wings, 
   thewoksoflife.com"},{"@type":"WebPage","@id":"https://thewoksoflife.com/baked-white-pepper- 
   chicken-wings/#webpage","url":"https://thewoksoflife.com/baked-white-pepper-chicken- 
   wings/","inLanguage":"en-US","name":"Baked White Pepper Chicken Wings | The Woks of 
   Life", .................. #continues onwards
```

**I am trying to access the "name" (as well as other similarly unaccessable elements) located at the end of the code snippet above, but am unable to do so. 
Any help would be appreciated!**

Comment: _but am unable to do so._ What did you try, and why didn't it work?

Comment: The answer below worked for me, but since I am new to web scraping, I had a lot of questions and attempted a couple approaches that failed. There's the aforementioned .get("name") that didn't appear to do anything, but I also tried stripping the resulting string with regex, but since there are multiple "names" as well as some other duplicates, it didn't exactly print what I wanted.

Comment: Which "name" do you want, how can you tell which one it is?

Comment: There is a "name" object for Woks of Life, and a name object for "Baked White Pepper Chicken Wings".

Answer (score 0):

The data is in JSON format, so after locating the `<script>` tag, you can parse it with JSON module. For exemple:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://thewoksoflife.com/baked-white-pepper-chicken-wings/'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

data = json.loads( soup.select_one('script.yoast-schema-graph.yoast-schema-graph--main').text )
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))  # <-- uncomment this to print all data

recipe = next((g for g in data['@graph'] if g.get('@type', '') == 'Recipe'), None)
if recipe:
    print('Name        =', recipe['name'])
    print('Cook Time   =', recipe['cookTime'])
    print('Ingredients =', recipe['recipeIngredient'])
    # ... etc.
```

Prints:

```
Name        = Baked White Pepper Chicken Wings
Cook Time   = PT40M
Ingredients = ['3 pounds whole chicken wings ((about 14 wings))', '1-2 tablespoons white pepper powder ((divided))', '2 teaspoons salt ((divided))', '1 teaspoon Sichuan peppercorn powder ((optional))', '2 teaspoons vegetable oil ((plus more for brushing))', '1/2 cup all purpose flour', '1/4 cup cornstarch']
```

Comment: Beautiful, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: `requests.get(url).text` --> `requests.get(url).content` would be better, I think.